# PHP date time format - 2012-08-16T21:14:03.447?

Tags: php, mysql

What format is this date time in PHP 2012-08-16T21:14:03.447?
How can I convert it to Timestamp and vice versa?

I have a timestamp format `1345108443790`, how to get the Date time ?

**For the people who downvoted/close request this question:**

I was getting weird result when trying to convert `1345108443790` (I got this value from third-party website) to DateTime, but after many attempts and @Truth's suggestion got to know that after trimming last 3 digits (may be microseconds?) and then passing it in function actually solved it and is giving the right result. Something to learn here, one click downvoters!

Comment: wow 2 downvotes.. and without reason!!

Comment: 3* (not me), and it's because your question is http://pokit.org/get/img/ad788f588cbe881f6c384f25282355f8.png, in short, this is incredibly basic PHP, and is well documented in the manual and in Google.

Comment: I have 6 years of PHP experience and already tried php datetime functions at the first place, but the solution I wanted was something weird that's why I asked here.

Comment: In that case, you should have mentioned what you've tried, shouldn't you?

Comment: @Truth please check my updated question. My rep doesn't speak that I am not a newbie here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: TBH, I've seen people with higher reputation than yours asking far stupider questions. But the idea is to give the correct details (i.e. what you've tried, and how it failed).

Comment: -1 — "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @Truth yes you are right. I must have specified how I was failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to ISO 8601 (Timezone is missing though), a.k.a. *the* standard for date/time stamps.

Use `strtotime()` it parses it correctly. You may want to consider `DateTime` objects as well.

Working example:

```
$ts = strtotime("2012-08-16T21:14:03.447");
echo date("H:i:s Y-m-d", $ts);
```

Comment: Shouldn't [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) times include a timezone designation?  Since it's lacking, this format isn't ISO 8601 compliant.  Moreover, since PHP/UNIX timestamps are to the second, won't the fractional part be lost here?

Comment: do you know how to convert 1345108443790 (timestamp) to datetime? I tried `date('Y-m-d','1345108443790')` without luck

Comment: @KalpeshMehta: Added working example.

Comment: That's great. But do you know if it is possible from timestamp to datetime? like `strtotime('1345108443790')` to Y-m-d?

Comment: @KalpeshMehta: Added, Working, Example.

Comment: You should not present the integer in quotes, but this: date('Y-m-d',1345108443790);

Comment: I tried `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1345108443790 ) ;` it's giving me `44594-10-15 23:53:10`

Comment: @Truth how can we convert `1345108443790` to datetime? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @KalpeshMehta: How did you get to 1345108443790?? I get 1345144443, which is about 1000 times smaller...

Comment: @Truth I am getting the value from remote site via curl.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta: Then the value is incorrect. I copied the timestamp you've shared in your original question, and got that value, there's no reason you should get anything else.

Comment: @Truth Okay. Finally cracked it. If you trim last three digits in `1345108443790` you will get proper datetime value. may be it's the microseconds attached?

Comment: @KalpeshMehta: I've pasted it with the microseconds and it worked fine. Are you sure the timestamp looks exactly like you've pasted?

Comment: @eggyal no, ISO 8601 does not *require* the timezone part. And PHP's DateTime class happily handles microsecond precision.

Comment: @CCInc: Have any **constructive** comment? If not, please keep those to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> What format is this date time in PHP 2012-08-16T21:14:03.447?

This format is covered in the [ISO 8601 International Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), albeit not a particularly commonly used example.

<sup>Aside: it is recommended (in the standard) that the fraction of seconds be preceded by a comma rather than a dot.</sup>

---

> How can I convert it to Timestamp and vice versa?

As one ordinarily would, with [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) or the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/class.datetime) class.

```
$subject = '2012-08-16T21:14:03.447';

echo date('r', strtotime($subject));
// or
$datetime = new DateTime($subject);
echo $datetime->format('r');
```

---

> I have a timestamp format 1345108443790, how to get the Date time ?

This is [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), but using milliseconds as the unit. Basic arithmetic will give you a Unix time in seconds, and from that you can create a `DateTime` object using the `@1234567890` format.

```
$subject = 1345108443790;
$unixtime = (int) ($subject / 1000);

echo date('r', $unixtime);
// or
$datetime = new DateTime("@$unixtime");
echo $datetime->format('r');
```

If you need the millisecond precision, then you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat).

```
$subject = 1345108443790;
$unixtime = (int) ($subject / 1000);
$millis   = $subject % 1000;

$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U u', "$unixtime $millis");
echo $datetime->format('r u');
```

Comment: i did it without DateTime object.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta Um, great?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@Truth's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132820/623041) to use PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects, as since v5.2.2 such can handle microseconds without problem:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2012-08-16T21:14:03.447');
$timestamp = $dt->format('U.u');                  // 1345151643.447000
$timestrng = $dt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u');       // 2012-08-16T21:14:03.447000
```